# Windows API W7 JumpList only for .NET?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, windows-7

I'm looking for a way to use JumpLists through plain C or C++ using the Windows API.

The [Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) seems to be only available for .NET.

Is there anyway to implement them using C/C++ wothout .NET?
I mean how is this possible:

- http://www.strixcode.com/q7goodies/ 
  -> C++
- http://www.strixcode.com/j7goodies/ 
  -> Java

Comment: Interesting how .NET is becoming the new Win32 API :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it's available for native developers. You were looking in the wrong place.

Here's a link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378460(v=VS.85).aspx#custom_jump_lists